# WebCrypto: Safe conversion from RSA-OAEP to RSA-PSS

Tags: security, rsa, webcrypto-api

WebCrypto supports RSA but forces you to choose the padding scheme for the different operations you can perform. RSA can perform both signing/verification and encryption/decryption (+key wrapping) but that is not very possible with the webcrypto API.

When I generate an RSA key using RSA-OAEP, the same key could be used for RSA-PSS, however there's no clear way to move around those using the webcrypto API.

My original thought was to take these steps to convert keys:

1. export the key using `exportKey` with `jwk`
2. "fix" `alg` from (for example) `RSA-OAEP-512` to `PS512`
3. "fix" `key_ops`

   a. `encrypt`-> `verify`

   b. `decrypt` -> `sign`
4. Import the "fixed" key with the correct algorithm

This system breaks down when the key is not-exportable, which I want to do for extra security of private keys (malicious scripts, self-xss, etc).

What would be a good way to "convert" between algorithm types but keeping the key without the ability to export?

Comment: Exporting the privateKey as pkcs8 and then importing it via RSA-PSS works as well and does not need steps 2-3! Same thing for the public key if you use spki.

However the issue still stands, it requires the key to be extractable...

Answer (score 3):

The webcrypto API do not allow to use a key for signing and encryption. Probably because this practice is not recommended. See this answer https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/12138/42888

> **it is safe, cryptographically speaking, to use the same RSA key pair for signature and encryption**, provided that the key pair is used safely for signature and used safely for encryption.
>
> **However this is a bad idea for a different reason: key management**. Signature keys and encryption keys have different requirements in terms of backups, access control, repudiation, etc. The fallback for a signature key in case of a catastrophic event is to destroy it to avoid future forgeries, so a signature key does not need to be backed up extensively. Conversely, the fallback for an encryption key is to keep it around to decrypt existing documents, so it needs to be backed up reliably.

To answer your question, you could:

1. Generate the RSA key as extractable,
2. Export it to pcks8 or jwk
3. Import it twice as non-extractable: key1-> `RSA-OAEP`, key2-> `RSA-PSS`
4. Destroy the original and extractable key

Then, the resulting keys are equal and non-extractable, and the original key has only be managed in browser memory.

Since you are going to get two keys in the browser, if the receivers of the public key are different, consider to generate distinct keys for signing and encryption

Comment: Is key management the only reason for this? The (private) key is saved on the server and is treated strictly as an encryption key.
As for your solution, that's what I was trying to avoid, since there is a small window of time where the key is extractable and I would ideally like to eliminate it.

Comment: I guess you mean you are saving the **public key** on the server .I do not see another solution to duplicate the key with the Webcrypto  API that temporarily have the key as extractable. Check also this [post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1806/why-should-one-not-use-the-same-asymmetric-key-for-encryption-as-they-do-for-sig) about signing/encryption with the same key. Key management (backup, non-repudiation, expiration time, destroying keys) is a reason, but they also name potential security risks